# in vim, enter is being mapped to a ctrl key custom key map

Tags: vim, mapping

I am encountering some strange behavior with a keymap in vim that uses the ctrl key. I would guess that this has a simple cause and solution, but I just can't see it.

During the editing of restructuredtext, I find myself typing things like

```
:math:`x`
```

often (this :math: role will cause whatever is inside the ticks to be typeset as math in e.g. the latex output).

I want to map a key like <kbd>m</kbd> to enter :math:`` into the text and position the cursor inside the ticks.

I have done this

```
map m i:math:``ha
```

and that seems to work fine.

However, I would like to be able to use this map in insert mode. For that, I thought that using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> would be best. I've done

```
imap <c-m> :math:``ha
```

Although that correctly inputs :math:`` and positions the cursor inside the ticks when I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, the trouble is that after this point, every time I press <kbd>enter</kbd> in insert mode, it runs the same command as if I typed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. In other words, enter in insert mode now seems to be mapped to

```
:math:``ha
```

as well.

It seems like it is definitely something to do with using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. If I bind e.g. the <kbd>F5</kbd> key as follows

```
imap <F5> :math:``ha
```

everything is fine.

I can use the e.g. <kbd>F5</kbd> key and save myself any further bother, but I would like to know what is going on for future reference.

Is there something basic about the use of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key in a key map that I am missing?

thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a different control combination for your mapping, e.g. `<C-g>`.

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today without these side effects, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Thanks for pointing all this out. I was not aware that these issues occurred. I think I may try to avoid the ctrl key in the key maps. As I mentioned, one of the F key would be fine for me too.

Answer (score 2):

if you do a

```
:h keycodes
```

you will see:

```
notation    meaning         equivalent  decimal value(s)    ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
....

<CR>        carriage return     CTRL-M   13 *carriage-return*
<Return>    same as <CR>                *<Return>*
<Enter>     same as <CR>                *<Enter>*
```

so it tells, `<c-m>` is same as `<Enter>` (same keycode 13)

you could test in your shell too, for example, type `ls` and then `<c-m>` instead of `<Enter>`

Comment: Well, I did not know that CTRL-M was a carriage-return in the shell etc. Thanks for pointing this out. The behaviour of vim makes a lot of sense now.