# How to map a sequence in vim conditionally to run external programs without printing the else clause

Tags: vim

How can I map a sequence in `vim` conditionally to run any of two external programs in such way that the screen is **not** cleared to show the `else` clause?

For example:

```
:nmap <c-l> :if filereadable('Makefile')<CR>!make<CR>else<CR>!ls<CR>endif<CR>
```

`ctrl`+`m` executes `make` but then clears the screen and prints the following at the bottom of it:

```
:  else
:  !ls
:  endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an *expression mapping* (`:help map-expr`)

```
:nnoremap <expr> <c-m> filereadable('Makefile') ? ':make<CR>' : ':!ls<CR>'
```

Notes:

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `<C-m>` is the same as `<CR>`; there's currently no way to distinguish the two; better use different keys. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768723/813602) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

you need `map <expr>`

e.g.:

```
nnoremap <expr> <c-t> line('.')>=6? ':!ls<cr>' : ':!seq 10<cr>'
```

in your example:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <c-m> filereadable('Makefile') ? ':make<CR>' : ':!ls<CR>'
```

for detail info:

```
:h :map-<expr>
```

note that, if you map `<c-m>`, the `Enter` will follow that mapping too. better use another key combination, unless you intend to do so.